# Zoom focus issue with gmaps4rails gem-placemarks only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary, zooming, gmaps4rails

I've browsed the other links in regards to this but I can't get it to work as desired.

What I have:

Index page: shows all the placemarks, working as intended.

Now for the show page: So I'm on the index page and click an individual link to get to the show page for that particular marker. When I click it, it's fairly zoomed in.

I want to have it so it is not THAT zoomed in. I don't want to use auto_adjust => false, because I want the map to be focused on that placemark.

When I set auto adjust to true and toy with the zoom, the zoom doesnt do anything, it just stays zoomed in as before (ie without using map options).

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `auto_zoom` option.

[See doc.](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/%28Multiple%29-Maps)

Comment: Well, I mean, it essentially is auto_zoom without auto_zoom. Adding "auto_zoom" isn't changing the zoom whatsoever. Wouldn't I want auto_adjust with a zoom value? Like I said, it's zoomed in fine, but I just want to zoom it out a little bit upon viewing it.

Comment: Here's an image with how it looks normally in the map show page, zoom not modified. http://i.imgur.com/fOPbc.png

Comment: Read the doc, it's clearly written auto adjust and auto_zoom are meant to be used together